# Json serialisation with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

is it possible with JsonConvert to not serialise a field when this field is null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObj, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look into the JsonSerializerSettings and its NullValueHandling property.